Eliminar lo último de una fila en bash
Tengo un archivo que contiene esto:
...
1 dog, 300.0ms
(no detections), 43443.9ms
3 cat, 4340ms
1 person, 1 cup, 1 laptop, 345ms
...

Y quiero que todas las filas queden de esta manera:
...
1 dog
no detections
3 cat
1 person, 1 cup, 1 laptop
...

con que comandos prodia lograr esto? he intentado con sed pero sin exito, gracias.

sed "s/, \S*$//" input.txt

@CandidMoe Muchas gracias, me sirvio!

Intenta con:
grep -Po '.*(?=, .+ms$)' archivo

Que lo que hace es buscar todo lo que este antes del patrón:

coma,
seguido de un espacio
seguido de varios caracteres
seguido de la cadena "ms"
todo antes del final de línea

